# Get social share count in python

Tags: python, socialshare

I am using python package here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/socialshares/0.3.2

As mentioned on this page, I am not getting any results neither in command line nor through python script. The following command returns nothing:

> socialshares http://www.theguardian.com/politics twitter google
>   facebook pinterest reddit --retry 10

Can anyone help me? What is the reason for returning nothing?

Answer (score 1):

Twitter has discontinued its api which returns social share count. After eliminating twitter from the list of platforms, the command returns results.